# meteor js database connection and create tables?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am new to `meteor`. Can anyone please tell me how to make a database connection and how to access data from the database? 
I have a clone of the GitHub application working fine for me but not understand where in the database connection file and where database tables exist and files are linked to access the data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

### Database connection and location

Meteor projects use `MongoDB` by default out of the box using the `mongo` core package.

The connection mode and target are determined by [environment variables](https://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/environment-variables.html).

> - `MONGO_URL`
>     (development, production)
>
>   MongoDB server URL. Give a fully qualified URL (or comma-separated list of URLs) like
>     `MONGO_URL="mongodb://user:password@myserver.com:10139"`. 
>     For more information see the MongoDB docs.
> - MONGO_OPLOG_URL
>     (development, production)
>
>   MongoDB server oplog URL. If you’re using a replica set (which you should), construct this url like so:
>     `MONGO_OPLOG_URL="mongodb://user:password@myserver.com:10139/local?replicaSet=(your replica set)&authSource=(your auth source)"`

The `MONGO_URL` is required in a built application (normally running in production).

In development mode (i.e, run by the `meteor run` command, which is likely the case in your scenario), if the above environment variables are not set, the Meteor utility creates a **default database** (stored inside the `.meteor` directory) and runs it at the next available port following your app's port (e.t, on the default port `3000`, the DB will be available at port `3001`).

The `meteor mongo -U` command prints out the mongo connection string. It is typically something like `mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor` for the default settings.

This means you can access it from your console (BTW, the `meteor mongo` command gives you a DB prompt) or a GUI database inspector.

The `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` is used for enhancing performance.

### Collection creation

The `mongo` package does not create collections if there is no need to, so simply declaring a `Mongo.Collection` in your code will not immediately create it. Some operations trigger the creation of a non-existing collections. For example, inserting a document or creating an index.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you create an instance of `Mongo.Collection` it connects to the MongoDB collection/table of the same name. If that table doesn't exist, it will be created for you when you insert your first document/row.

I strongly recommend the official meteor tutorial if you are new to meteor

Answer (score 0):

it's so easy to handle collections with mongoDB in meteor
I recommend you to read the meteor documentation 
https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html

or you can see the meteor tutorials https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections

or you can see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdbJPTsE2gQ&t=84s